# Python Flask JS XMLHttpRequest getting 404 not found

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

i'm still new to programming and i come across this problem. I tried to look for solution but havent found any yet. Hence im posting my question here:
The idea is pretty straightforward, so I want to update my homepage locally by selecting options. For every option is selected, there will be a different image appeared under the select form.
I'm putting "Perlis" as an example below for selecting state. The error came back "Perlis.html" not found. And I don't understand why.

My HTML & JS code:

```
{% block main %}
    <h1>Do you know what animals are threatened in Malaysia?</h1>
    <h4>Select your state and find out now.</h4>
    <form action="/" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" onchange="change(this.value);">
                <option disabled selected value>State</option>
                {% for state in states %}
                <option value="{{ state.state }}">{{ state.state }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    <div id="animal"></div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function change(name)
        {
            //deal with situation where nothing selected
            if(name == "")
            return;

            //create a new AJAX object
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //when page is loaded, have a callback function pre-fill our div
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("animal").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
            };

            //open the requested file and transmit the data
            ajax.open('GET', name + '.html', true);
            ajax.send();
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

My python code:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
        states= db.execute("SELECT state FROM endangered")
        return render_template("index.html", states=states)
```

one of the request file (Perlis.html):

```
<p>Hornbill</p>
<img src="static/Hornbill.jpeg" />
```

Error message 404 Perlis.html not found:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uStzL.png)

I'm wondering could it be something to do with my backend server code? Did I miss something connecting them?

Please advise, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify how do you deploy your `Perlis.html` and why do you expect it to load?

Comment: Hi, I expect it to load within "animal" div. I did it according to this short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQcBs4S-wEQ
The video doesnt cover the backend code tho, i guess my error comes from there?

Comment: Do I need a different route to receive the data from Perlis.html? if yes, how would the code looks like?